# Can't set the meta viewport width back to the screen's width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, viewport, meta-tags

I am trying to get my script to:

1. by clicking on a link (#breakCSSButton), change the meta tag's viewport width to 1280 resizing it.
2. by clicking on the link again, change the meta tag's viewport width back to window.screen.width

I dont understand why its not working. I have an anchor tag button:

`<a href="#" id="breakCSSButton">`

Heres the code:

```
$(function () {
if ( $('#breakCSSButton').hasClass('dviewToggledOn') == false ) {
    console.log($('#breakCSSButton').hasClass('dviewToggledOn'));
    $('#breakCSSButton').on('click', function () {
        viewportBreak = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
        viewportBreak.setAttribute('content', 'user-scalable=1, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=4, width=1280');
        $( window ).resize();
        $('#breakCSSButton').toggleClass('dviewToggledOn');
    });
}
if ( $('#breakCSSButton').hasClass('dviewToggledOn') == true ) {
    $('.dviewToggledOn').on('click', function () {
        deviceScreenWidth = window.screen.width;
        viewportBreak = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
        viewportBreak.setAttribute('content', "user-scalable=1, width=" + deviceScreenWidth + ", initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=4");
        $( window ).resize();
        $('#breakCSSButton').toggleClass('dviewToggledOn');
    });
}

});
```

Comment: The `$(function () { /* ... */ })` code runs once after the page has loaded. So you're checking the class, setting the click handler, etc. when the page loads. You should be making those checks and changing behaviour _within_ the click handler, so that it checks every time the link is clicked.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat I'm not sure if the bottom answer is what you mean. It didn't work. :(

Comment: the meta tags are parsed when the page loads, you can't update them later on and expect them to change anything; you need to reload, but reloading will reset the changes, so basically, you can't do that...

Comment: @nakji That is what I meant; that would fix the logic part. But I think Dan is probably right.

Comment: @dandavis Well I'm not so sure about that as the first click toggles the view and restyles the page according to a 1280 viewport width. The problem comes when I try to change the viewport a second time by the window.screen.width property (trying to revert the view of the page to the original width before the user clicked on the "Desktop View" button/link. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@Whothehellisthat That didn't seem to work... is this what you mean?:

```
$('#breakCSSButton').on('click', function () {
if ( $('#breakCSSButton').hasClass('dviewToggledOn') == false ) {
  viewportBreak = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
    viewportBreak.setAttribute('content', 'user-scalable=1, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=4, width=1280');
    $( window ).resize();
    $('#breakCSSButton').toggleClass('dviewToggledOn');
  }

if ( $('#breakCSSButton').hasClass('dviewToggledOn') == true ) {
  deviceScreenWidth = window.screen.width;
    viewportBreak = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
    viewportBreak.setAttribute('content', "user-scalable=1, width=" + deviceScreenWidth + ", initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=4");
    $( window ).resize();
    $('#breakCSSButton').toggleClass('dviewToggledOn');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay the following works. I decided to do a .show and .hide on two different html buttons. The code is simpler this way. I think the problem is that it didn't like working on the same element (#breakCSSButton) after more than 1 dynamic change (i.e. adding a class and working on it). It may also have been recognizing the click actions on the same class and running both if statements based on a single click...

```
    $(function () {
      $('#breakCSSButton').on('click', function () {
            viewportBreak = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
            viewportBreak.setAttribute('content', 'user-scalable=1, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=4, width=1280');
            $( window ).resize();
            $('#breakCSSButton').hide();
            $('#restoreCSSButton').show();
      });
     });

    $(function () {
      $('#restoreCSSButton').on('click', function () {
            deviceScreenWidth = window.screen.width;
            viewportBreak = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
            viewportBreak.setAttribute('content', "user-scalable=1, width=" + deviceScreenWidth + ", initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=4");
            $( window ).resize();
            $('#breakCSSButton').show();
            $('#restoreCSSButton').hide();
      });
     });
```